# Do 2.5Gb/s media converters exist?

Tags: media-conversion

I am looking for a media converter for a 2.5Gb/s ethernet connection that currently runs over cat6a.  I am wondering if there actually are 2.5Gb/s media converters out there, or if it requires settling for 1Gb/s or stepping up to significantly more expensive and less energy efficient 10Gb/s media converters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for an intermediate connection over fiber: there is no such fiber variant, so media converters for 2.5 Gbit/s don't exist.

2.5 and 5 Gbit/s are twisted pair only (and backplane, obviously). They are variants for legacy TP cabling that allows >1 Gbit/s over twisted-pair copper but doesn't support 10 Gbit/s.

2.5 and 5 Gbit/s ports basically use scaled-down 10G technology and are not really less expensive by themselves. Unless those speeds significantly catch on by themselves and economy-by-scale really comes into play, they will never become as cheap as 1 Gbit/s ports. And only then would fiber variants make any sense.